# How can I notify MapActivity from broadcast receiver to change Overlay, proximityalert etc

Tags: android, handler, broadcast

I have registered ProximityAlert in MapActivity. No problem with catching alerts in BroadcastReceiver and starting new Activity.

Beside starting new activity I want to notify MapActivity to clear overlay, proximity alert and stop count up timer.

Because broadcast receiver is in separate thread I was make a handler

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {
private ProximityMapActivity MainActivity;

MyHandler(ProximityMapActivity a) {
    this.MainActivity = a;
}...
```

in MapActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handler = new MyHandler(this);
```

I have no problem with Handler from runOnFirstFix runnable I can start a count up timer.
But broadbast receiver is in separate class and I have no clue what to do

```
private MyHandler handler;
...
handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);
```

is give me null pointer exeption. When I add

```
handler= new MyHandler(new ProximityMapActivity());
```

Uncaught handler comes out.

Can you give me a hint or comment? Thank You in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add setter to my object. Now I can pass on the pointer of handler.

in MapActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    handler = new MyHandler(this);
ProximityAlertHelper.setHandler(handler);
```